# Powershell: Embedded Hashtable writing to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, nested, hashtable

Currently trying to write a Hashtable to a CSV file. The Format I am looking for is

| IP | Ports |
| --- | --- |
| IP | Port |
|  | Port |
|  | Port |
| IP | Port |
|  | Port |
|  | Port |

I have encountered two problems while doing this.

1.)

| IP | Ports |
| --- | --- |
| IP | System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry etc... |
| IP | System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry etc... |
| IP | System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry etc... |
| IP | System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry etc... |

2.)

| #TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IP | IP | IP | IP | IP |
| @{Port=; Port=; Port=;....} | @{Port=; Port=; Port=;...} | @{Port=; Port=; Port=;...} | @{Port=; Port=; Port=;...} | @{Port=; Port=; Port=;...} |

Below is the code

```
$filepath = "ip.csv"
$host_list = Import-Csv $filepath

$hash = @{}
$host_list | ForEach-Object{
    if($hash.ContainsKey($_.IP)){
            $IP = $_.IP
            if($hash.$IP.ContainsKey($_.Port)){
            }
            else{
                $Port = $_.Port
                $hash.$IP.$Port = @{}
            }
    }
    else{
        $IP = $_.IP
        $hash.$IP = @{}
    }
}

##Gives Table 1 Csv output
ForEach-Object{$hash.GetEnumerator() | sort Name} |
   Select-Object -Property @{N='IP'; E ={$_.Key}}, @{N='Port'; E={$_.Value.GetEnumerator()}}|
   Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "IPList.csv"

##Gives Table 2 csv output 

$HashObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $hash
$HashObj | ConvertTo-Json |Set-Content -Path "IPList.json"

Get-Content IPList.json | ConvertFrom-Json | Export-Csv PlzWork.csv
```

Comment: A question to your desired format: Do the ports without an according IP are actually related to the IP "*above*" them?  And how does your CSV file look like? You may share some example rows of it. (formatted as code please)  ;-)

Comment: I don't see any sort of question being asked here, much less a **specific** one. You'll need to [edit] your post to ask a specific question related to the code you've posted. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Olaf I believe the answer to your question is yes. 
The Keys inside the $hash are also Hashtables.
I am very new to powershell, how do I share it as code? The Table 1 and 2 I created are what it looks like when I have attempted to export it. Do you want the original CSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired CSV output format is unusual, in that the rows aren't self-contained:

It sounds like you want an empty `IP` column to imply that the row's `Port` column value is associated with the `IP` value of the most recent row with a non-empty `IP` column value.

To get the format as described, try the following (to switch to a normal, self-contained row format, remove the `$ip = $null` statement):

```
$hash.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name | ForEach-Object { 
  $ip = $_.Name
  foreach ($port in $_.Value.Keys) { 
    [pscustomobject] @{ IP = $ip; Port = $port } # construct and output an object
    $ip = $null 
  }
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation IPList.cs
```

- To see the resulting objects in tabular form before exporting, omit the `| Export-Csv ...` call.
- To output the resulting CSV data as *strings*, by default to the display, replace `| Export-Csv ...` with `|` [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv)

Comment: It works perfectly! It is an unusual format request, I just wasn't sure if it was possible. Thank you for explaining how it works as well!